# Labor Productivity movers and determinants: regression form

Tags: econometrics, productivity

Consider a sample of firms' labor productivity over time. Some firms improve their productivity rating (i.e., jump from the lower to the higher productivity quartiles), some don't, and some stay unchanged.

Of those that jump up, I'd like to understand why: for example are these firms more IT intensive?

In terms of supprting regression evidence, would this fly? Would I simply regression share of movers against IT intensity, or would it require something like a tobit regression?